# Output of typer command is not visible in terminal

Tags: python, command-line-interface, pipenv, typer

I'm trying to use Typer package in python.

I wrote this code:

```
import typer


app = typer.Typer()


@app.command()
def hello(name: str):
    print(f"Hello {name}")
```

And I'm trying to run this with this command:

```
python main.py hello Patryk
```

And my terminal is not displaying anything. No errors, no text.

Python version: Python 3.9.13 (pipenv)
System: Macos Ventura 13.1
Terminal: iTerm2 Build 3.4.18 and Macos default terminal

I tried to not use pipenv and install all typer on my machine.

I also tried this piece of code:

```
import typer


def main(name: str):
    print(f"Hello {name}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    typer.run(main)
```

And it works when I run it with this command:

```
python main.py
```

Answer (score 0):

I found solution. To make it work you need to add:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app()
```

And have at least 2 commands, so your code has to look like this:

```
import typer


app = typer.Typer()


@app.command()
def hello(name: str):
    print(f"Hello {name}")


@app.command()
def goodbye(name: str):
    print(f"Goodbye {name}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app()
```

Comment: You don't have to give at least two commands.

Answer (score 0):

You just forgot to add this below:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app()
```

Then launch the app like this:

```
python main.py Patryk
```

because Typer has defined hello() as the default action if the program is executed. So there is no need to add the hello in front in this case.

Unless you add other commands in addition then you will have to specify the command to run at runtime:

```
python main.py <command-name> ...
```